# How to vaidate elements in each row of html table by jQuery ValidationEngine?

Tags: jquery, element, jquery-validation-engine

I want to validate value of inputs in each row separately using jquery validationEngine as you seen below, but it doesn't work properly and I'm not found any sample by this way.

Is there a way to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- script and styles resource here -->
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tr1').validationEngine();
        $('#tr2').validationEngine();
    });

    function validateRow(rowIndex) {
        var result = jQuery('#tr' + rowIndex).validationEngine('validate');
        $('#result').text(result);
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr id="tr1">
                <th>
                    Row
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header 1
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header 2
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="tr1" class="a validationEngineContainer">
                <td>
                    1
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="i1_1" type="text" class="validate[required]" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="i1_2" type="text" class="validate[required]" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="tr2" class="b validationEngineContainer">
                <td>
                    2
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="i2_1" type="text" class="validate[required]" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="i2_2" type="text" class="validate[required]" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="button" onclick="validateRow(1);" value="validate firs row"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="validateRow(2)" value="validate second row"/>
    <br>
    <label id="result"></label>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the id tr1 used twice which would probably screw things up

Answer (score 0):

I think your table should be wrapped in a `<form>` tag and you should use it's id instead of `<tr>`'s id in validationEngine.